# AES round key generation

Tags: aes

I was reading an article regarding AES algorithm. For Round 0 key generation, one of the steps is to add the round constant to the output from s-box.
ex: Byte Substitution (S-Box): (B7; 5A; 9D; 85)
 Adding round constant (01; 00; 00; 00) gives: g(w[3]) = (B6; 5A; 9D; 85)

Could someone explain how B6 is arrived at?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a simple XOR:

B **XOR** 0 = B
and
7 **XOR** 1 = 0111 **XOR** 0001 = 6